# Split Array in two parts such that sum of gcd of both parts is maximum

Tags: arrays, sorting, number-theory, greatest-common-divisor

Split a array into two non empty parts such that sum of gcd of first part and second part is maximum

I put largest element in first part and second largest in second part and then starting from the least elemnt among remaining check its GCD with each part and add it to a part having minimum loss in previous ans(sum of gcd upto now)

I guess i am missiing some corner cases

Comment: It is not true always, e.g. [1000, 700, 500] will have maximum GCD of 1200 as [1000, 500] & [700] but your method is giving 1001.

Comment: Also my algorithm will take [6] in first part [5] in other part then append 1,2,3,4 to [5] so answer will be 7

Comment: SO is not a place for this. This is a question from an ongoing programming challenge on codechef [https://www.codechef.com/JUNE19B/problems/SUMAGCD].

Answer (score 0):

Don't spoil the fun of competition, let others think and you should also try it by yourself rather posting here!